# how to substitute slash in a file using sed

Tags: bash, sed

I am in use of `bash` shell.

I have a file filelist:

```
    cat filelist
    ../1.txt
    ../2.txt
    ...
    ../100.txt
```

I want to remove "../" and I tried `$ cat filelist | sed s/..\///`
, but it gives an error message. How can i remove the slash?

Comment: You'll want to escape the `.`s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need quotes:

```
sed 's/..\///'
```

`.` means any character so you have to escape it too:

```
sed 's/\.\.\///'
```

and for readability you can use another character for the separator:

```
sed 's|\.\./||'
```

Comment: maybe the `^` for his request that is missing  (i guess) in the OP failing sed

Comment: @NeronLeVelu: obviously not. the main problem was that bash interprets those backslashes - changing the invoked command to `sed s/..///` - which is incorrect.

Comment: purpose of the comment was not the error itself, but the fact that OP seems to remove uppter folder relative to current batch folder reference and not path that contains `../` (so the use of *maybe* and the +1)

Answer (score 1):

You need quotes around the `sed` argument and also need to include the `g` global flag. It is also not necessary to `cat` the file first. You should also escape the periods.

Use:

```
sed 's/\.\.\///g' filelist
```

Gives:

```
1.txt
2.txt
...
100.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

remove starting `../` (i guess it's the purpose but not specified)

```
sed 's#^\.\./##' filelist
```

- escaping the dot for avoiding regex meaning
- changing default separator `/`by `#` to allow a readible `/` in path
- adding `^` for limiting to starting path and not changing something like `bad/../folder`. If not the wanted behavior, just remove this caret.
- direct use of file from sed (no need of cat with sed in this case)

Answer (score 0):

Use an alternate separator.

```
sed 's|^\.\./||g' filelist
```

You can also use the `-i` flag to edit the file in-place.

```
sed -i 's|^\.\./||g' filelist
```

Comment: The `-i` will change the behaviour from what OP did quite drastically.

Comment: @Biffen; true, explained.